# JQuery popup via a button toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a modal popup which has an `active class`, once this class is on the modal appears and once this class is off it disappears. I want a button to be able to be pressed and the modal appears and a close button in the modal which closes the modal. I am using JQuery so I have tried so far:

Jquery

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $(".modal").addClass(".active");
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

Html

```
<button>Modal</button>
```

Not active Modal Html

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id">
</div>
```

Active modal html

```
<div class="modal active" id="modal-id">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use dot before class name:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(".modal").addClass("active");
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thats great Cristiano, so how would I toggle it off

Comment: Especially on `addClass` method. For toggle, use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`

Answer (score 0):

You will need two `click` functions. One attached to the button that shows the modal, and one attached to the button on the modal that closes it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // Button that opens the modal
        $("#open-button").click(function(){
            $(".modal").addClass("active");
        });
    }); 

    // Button on the modal that closes the modal
        $("#close-button").click(function(){
            $(".modal").removeClass("active");
        });
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Two buttons are not needed. One can toggle the class and it's enough

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have a button on your popup. Along with your code append your popup html and add the extra click event on the close button.

```js
$('#show-popup').on('click', function(){
      $('.modal').addClass('active');
    });


$('#close-popup').on('click', function(){
  $('.modal').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
}

#close-popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-popup">Show</button>

<div class="modal" id="modal-id">
  <button id="close-popup">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, the method who are affecting the class attribute don't need to have a `.` it's not a selector but a string class name who is expecting.

For show/hide your modal on each click on the button you can use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".modal").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.modal{
 display:none;
 border:solid 1px black;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}

.modal.active{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Modal</button>

<div class="modal" id="modal-id">
modal
</div>
```